# got receive_from: Bad file descriptor while using boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

```cpp
#include "string"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
 
class A {
    public:
    std::string address;
    std::string port;
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    udp::socket socketInstance = udp::socket(io_context);
    udp::endpoint endpointSetup;
 
    explicit A(std::string addrs, std::string port) {
        this->address = addrs;
        this->port = port;
    }
 
    A(const A& a) {
        this->address = a.address;
        this->port = a.port;
    }
 
    void attachListener() {
        endpointSetup = udp::endpoint(make_address(address), std::stoi(port));
        socketInstance = udp::socket(io_context, endpointSetup);
    }
};
 
class B {
    public:
    A aClass;
 
    explicit B(const A& a) : aClass(a) {}
 
    void getData() {
        std::array<char, 1024> recv_buffer{};
 
        aClass.socketInstance.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer), aClass.endpointSetup);
    }
};
 
int main() {
    A a("192.168.1.49", "5080");
    a.attachListener();
    B b(a);
    b.getData();
}
```

The part `aClass.socketInstance.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer), aClass.endpointSetup);` creates the error `Bad file descriptor`.

I presume the `io_context` property in `class A` is destroyed somehow. Basically, what I want to achieve is to listen to some UDP port in a separate classes. How do I solve this?

Comment: The code shown doesn't compile.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: where can I find it for c++?

Comment: I fixed the code (moved the full example from pastebin into the question and fixed the `address` vs `ADDRESS` naming issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your declaration of the `aClass` member in `B`:

```
class B {
    public:
    A aClass;
 
    explicit B(const A& a) : aClass(a) {}
...
```

The `aClass` member is of type `A`, so when you do `aClass(a)`, a copy is performed. You have defined a copy constructor for `A`, but it does not copy the already opened socket, leaving you with a default-initialized (and therefore unopened) socket in the copy.

Consider the following example class:

```
class C {
public:
  std::string foo_ = "foo";
  C(const std::string &foo) : foo_{foo} {}
  C(const C &c) {}
};
```

If you would run the following code:

```
  C c{"bar"};
  C c2{c};
  std::cout << c2.foo_ << std::endl;
```

You would get the output `foo`. This is because the copy constructor for `C` does not copy the `foo_` member. Therefore, when `c2` is initialized, it will not take the value `bar` from `c`, but instead default-initialize the `foo_` member to `foo`. The same problem applies to the socket member of your `A` class.

### Solution 1

Avoid a copy by making `B` hold a pointer to to an `A`:

```
class B {
public:
  A* aClass;

  explicit B(A* a) : aClass(a) {}

  void getData() {
    std::array<char, 1024> recv_buffer{};

    aClass->socketInstance.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer),
                                       aClass->endpointSetup);
  }
};
```

And then in `main` do:

```
B b(&a);
```

This way, when you create a `B`, it will still have access to the socket you initialized for the original `A`.

Instead of using `A*`, you could also use a smart pointer, i.e. `std::unique_ptr<A>` or `std::shared_ptr<A>`, if you want to express ownership in the sense that the `B` owns the `A`, and thereby the socket held by `A`.

### Solution 2

An alternative solution would be to move-construct `A`, if you want to pass an `A` to `B` but also want `B` to take ownership of the socket held by the `A` instance, without using the indirection of a (smart) pointer.

This way you could take advantage of the move-constructor for the `udp::socket`. However, this would require you to move the `io_context` out of `A`, because the `io_context` does not have move-constructor.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

class A {
public:
  std::string address;
  uint16_t port;

  boost::asio::io_context &io_context;

  udp::socket socketInstance;
  udp::endpoint endpointSetup;

  explicit A(boost::asio::io_context &io_context, std::string addrs,
             uint16_t port)
      : io_context{io_context}, address{addrs}, port{port}, socketInstance{
                                                                io_context} {}

  void attachListener() {
    endpointSetup = udp::endpoint{make_address(address), port};
    socketInstance = udp::socket{io_context, endpointSetup};
  }
};

class B {
public:
  A aClass;

  explicit B(A &&a) : aClass{std::move(a)} {}

  void getData() {
    std::array<char, 1024> recv_buffer{};

    aClass.socketInstance.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer),
                                       aClass.endpointSetup);
  }
};

int main() {
  boost::asio::io_context io_context{};

  A a{io_context, "127.0.0.1", 5080};
  a.attachListener();
  B b{std::move(a)};
  b.getData();
}
```

Both solutions can be tested e.g. with

```
netcat --udp localhost 5080
```

Comment: thank you for you response. much appreciated. judging from the code above, I can tell C++ is not so friendly with OOP